# Flutter error in Dio https request. HandshakeException: Handshake error in client OS Error: (TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR(tls_record.cc:594))

Tags: flutter, ssl, https, dio

I am trying to send a `https` request from flutter with following function:

```
Future<void> sendOTP(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      final String url = 'https://127.0.0.1:5432/api/send_otp';

      final response = await _dio.post(
        url,
        data: {'number': 1234567890},
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        ),
      );

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw Exception("Failed to send OTP: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Failed to send OTP: ${e.error.toString()}");
    }
  }
```

To enable `ssl certificate` I have added following code in my main method:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ByteData data = await PlatformAssetBundle().load('asset/certificate/certificate.pem');
  SecurityContext.defaultContext
      .setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I have downloaded the `certificate.pem` file from https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-r3.pem.

When I am sending the request using `thunderclient` or `postman` with the certificate, it works but from the flutter app it throws following error:

```
Error: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
    TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR(tls_record.cc:594))
```

For server, I am using `actix-web` with `rustls` - if relevant. Please suggest how do I fix the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and after a few hours of research what I found:

- If you have an android emulator in the default configuration, you must be able to reach your url from the emulator´s browse in the following ip address: [https://10.0.2.2:[portNumber]/api](https://10.0.2.2:%5BportNumber%5D/api). According to the documentation, this is an alias for your localhost (your machine).
- I changed my asp.net api configuration to respond in the local machine wi-fi ip address, in my case is 192.168.100.2 as you can see in the picture bellow:
  [image]

As you can see, my API is reached by the android emulator but if I run my flutter code using Dio Http (Version 5.1.1) it throws a Handshake exception.
I tried the exactly the same code you use, added a certificate but nothing changed. I really don´t know what to do from now. It´s really frustrating, maybe I´ll have to develop my app using the brownser instead the emulator.

This is my dio base options configuration, wich is Ok:

[image]

This is the exception throwed by the Dio Http:
[image]

I also tried to add internet permission in the android manifest but nothing changed, I also tried to point to the http version of my API but the same error ocurred.
Maybe this is a bug of Dio Http?

Answer (score 0):

after a research I finally found the solution for this problem. Basically you have to add the following code when creating a Dio instance:

```
class DioSingleton {
  static final baseOptions = BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: "https://10.0.2.2:7027/api/",
  );

  static Dio createInstance() {
    var dio = Dio(baseOptions);
    dio.httpClientAdapter = IOHttpClientAdapter(
      onHttpClientCreate: (client) {
        client.badCertificateCallback =
            (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
        return client;
      },
    );
    return dio;
  }
}
```

Also, you dont need to configure the Android emulator to use proxy or any different configuration. Just use this "as is" and everything will work.
Remember to use the address 10.0.2.2 if you have a localhost api running on your machine. In my case, I have an .net6 API running in localhost.
Please mark this as the accepeted answer if this solved your problem.